# Verificar se Registo Existe em BD SQLite e caso não exista Retornar Mensagem

Tags: android, sqlite

Boas noite,

Estou a tentar fazer uma pequena app que consiste pesquisar numa base de dados SQLite. Para a pesquisa irei usar duas formas, ou seja através do Numero ONU e através do Nome.

No entanto estou a deparar-me com um problema, a app estoura no caso de se tentar pesquisar sobre algum registo que não exista.

Como poderei fazer para que seja despoletada uma mensagem de erro no caso da pesquisa não encontrar um resultado?

DbHelper:

```
//Metodo ONU Query
public List<Elemento> getONU()
{
    List<Elemento> listaElementos = new ArrayList<Elemento>();

    //Seleccionar Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT *FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ONU = " + MainActivity.editText_ONU_search.getText();
    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //Loop por todas as linhas da BD e adiciona-las a lista
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
            Elemento element = new Elemento();
            element.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            element.setONU(cursor.getInt(1));
            element.setNOME_SUB(cursor.getString(2));
            listaElementos.add(element);

    }

    //Return listaElementos;
    return listaElementos;

}

//Metodo Nome Query
public List<Elemento> getNomeSubstancia()
{
    List<Elemento> listaElementos = new ArrayList<Elemento>();

    //Seleccionar Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE NOME_SUB = '" + MainActivity.editText_NOME_search.getText() + "'";
    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //Loop por todas as linhas da BD e adiciona-las a lista
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
            Elemento element = new Elemento();
            element.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            element.setONU(cursor.getInt(1));
            element.setNOME_SUB(cursor.getString(2));
            listaElementos.add(element);

    }

    //Return listaElementos;
    return listaElementos;

}
```

OnuResultActivity:

```
public class OnuResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declaração de variaveis
List<Elemento> listaElementos;
int elemento_id = 0;

Elemento currentElemento;
TextView textView_onu, textView_nome_sub;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onu_result);

    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
    listaElementos = db.getONU();
    currentElemento = listaElementos.get(elemento_id);

    textView_onu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_onu);
    textView_nome_sub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_nome_sub);

    //Apresentar Info
    setElementosView();

}

private void setElementosView() {

    textView_onu.setText(Integer.toString(currentElemento.getONU()));
    textView_nome_sub.setText(String.valueOf(currentElemento.getNOME_SUB()));


    elemento_id++;
}
```

}

NomeResultActivity:

```
public class NomeResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaração de variaveis
    List<Elemento> listaElementos;
    int elemento_id = 0;

    Elemento currentElemento;
    TextView textView_onu, textView_nome_sub;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nome_result);

        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        listaElementos = db.getNomeSubstancia();
        currentElemento = listaElementos.get(elemento_id);

        textView_onu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_onu);
        textView_nome_sub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_nome_sub);

        //Apresentar Info
        setElementosView();
    }

    private void setElementosView() {

        textView_onu.setText(Integer.toString(currentElemento.getONU()));
        textView_nome_sub.setText(String.valueOf(currentElemento.getNOME_SUB()));

        elemento_id++;
    }
}
```

Alguma ideia de como poderei retornar uma mensagem de aviso quando a pesquisa não é encontrada de forma a cobrir a possibilidade de a pesquisa inserida pelo utilizador ser não corresponder ao que está na BD.

Cumprimentos

Answer (score 0):

O jeito que eu faço esse tipo de tarefa e o seguinte, logo apos a consulta eu faço uma comparacao para ver se a consulta retornou algum resultado, entao eu pego meu Cursor e verifico ele, if(cursor.getCount() == 0){ mensagem }, dessa forma se nao tiver registros no banco vai retornar 0 linhas, por curiosidade de onde vc é ? boa sorte nos estudos

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_onu_result);

DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
listaElementos = db.getONU();

if(listaElementos.size() > 0){
   currentElemento = listaElementos.get(elemento_id);
}else{
  //AQUI VOCÊ PODE USAR UM TOAST OU UM DIALGO PRA EXIBIR A 
  //MENSAGEM QUE QUISER
}
textView_onu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_onu);
textView_nome_sub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_nome_sub);

//Apresentar Info
setElementosView();

}
```

Acho que foi isso que entendi da sua pergunta.